# Stsadm restore issue

Tags: 2007, stsadm, backup, restore

I try to restore Sharepoint 2007 site using STSAdm  but the previous operation failed , I checked the event viewer and found the following information :

Faulting application mssdmn.exe, version 12.0.4518.1015, stamp 4543a352, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3053, stamp 4889dc18, debug? 0, fault address 0x00044f6a.

Is There any idea ??

Comment: I think we're going to need more information.  Is there anything in the ULS logs?

Comment: what was the full syntax of the command you tried to execute?

Answer (score 1):

Have you applied the latest service packs for MOSS?

You will need to check your SharePoint logs and Windows event logs and perhaps update your question to add any relevant information.

If that doesn't help you, and you are desperate to get the content back, you could try opening the SharePoint backup cab and trying to restore the individual content databases using SQL Server, then try to attach them.

Answer (score 1):

Mscorwks.dll is a .NET framework library implementing parts of the System.IO namespace including serialization. I suspect the error is just a generic exception related to being unable to read the site backup file correctly. Was the site based on a custom site definition?